# Adjustable screw positioning

Tags: tools

[image]I'm looking for the name of part which I'm pretty sure exists.  It works similar to how the seat on a exercise weight machine works.

It's a plastic band which has a bunch of connected figure 8s cut out.  Which will allow you to adjust the position of a bolt.

Can someone tell me the name of this?

**Edit:**  Believe it's similar to an L-Track, I basically need something with adjustable anchor points.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you can tell me that, then I look up what you're trying to find.

Comment: I'm basically, trying to find a plastic track which you can wrap around your head, that has multiple adjustable nodes, so they can be positioned differently along your head

Comment: Couldn't find something like that, as of now. So if you need it I could model it for you in CAD if you can give me a rough sketch to work on.

Comment: Can you add a photo, diagram, or both?

Comment: I've added a rough sketch, the thing I want would be much longer, I just didn't want to draw all the anchor points

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Snapback-Plastic-Replacement-Repair-Strap/dp/B01J6KA4RI

Comment: @represton I want the anchors to be move able on the track, I would prefer if I didn't have to take them off the track to move them like a snapback

Comment: @johnny5 https://i.imgur.com/CyHWRVx.png This is just too simple, a better design is possible.... still thinking of how to do that.

Comment: @ManuG yeah me too, this was the only way I could think of at the moment but I'm sure there's an easier way